# Updating Google Play Services from 8.4.0 to 9.2.1 breaks a bunch of code involving com.google.android.gms.location.places

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have updated Google play services and now a bunch of classes seem to be missing:

```
com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter
com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction
com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer
com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places
com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place
com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer
com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihood
com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihoodBuffer
```

I have looked at the release notes https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases and the API references https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/package-summary but there is no indication that these classes have been replaced.

Can anyone advise me on what is going on please?

Thanks,

Riz

Edit: here is the gradle build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
    compile.exclude module: 'guava:19.0-rc2'

    all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'

    androidTestCompile.exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
    androidTestCompile.exclude module: 'jsr305:2.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    //project
    compile project(':MyGeneralLibrary')

    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.2.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
    compile 'com.github.scribejava:scribejava-apis:2.2.2'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'

    //unit tests
    testCompile project(':TestUtils')
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0'

    //instrumentation tests
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.01"
        applicationId "com.chdryra.android.reviewer"
        testInstrumentationRunner    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/androidTest/res']
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you still have the above issue please change the gradle build file to include the two following lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1'
```

google separate the places package into individual API...

Comment: Thanks I did that which fixed the above issue but created a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38464876/revisions

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into a similar problem few days ago. You have to check the other libraries if they are using Google Play Services and what version. If your import is higher/lower than the other library imports then it breaks the app. Check if there are updates available for the other libraries with implementation of the higher Google Play Services.

We solved it with updating the conflicting library.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! How do I check other libraries to see if they reply on older versions of play services?

Comment: Try googling for them. The best way would be to read the stacktrace 
properly and narrow the libraries which are causing the errors. It depends on the library you use. Most of them are on github and you can check there if there were any updates to higher version and you can also check their gradle build files what libs they are using

Comment: This is a compile time error (failure to import) not run time so can't use stack trace.

Comment: Can you provide your gradle build file?